# Excel 365 Power Query: 'Data from picture' is the only option available, how can I access 'From table/range'?

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-365

I'm trying to load my data into power query on excel 365, but on my data tab, the only option available is 'Data from picture'. I'm trying to access 'From table/range'.
Please help

I also went to File>Options hoping to be able to see COM.addins and select power query, but the only option found there was 'Regional Format Settings'

Comment: "Viewing and refreshing queries is available to all Office 365 Subscribers.
Additional functionality is available to all Office 365 Subscribers with Business or Enterprise plans.". What level of subscription are you using?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about Excel for Web, not Excel for Desktop, correct? Mine works the same way - I have all the get data options on desktop, but not on web. I generally just accept that the web version is not really Excel, and am not surprised when features are missing.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the excel for web. I'd try it on desktop and see if it works. Thank you